# cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Couldn't load XPCOM

Tags: firefox, centos

Firefox install after centos i get this error

cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Couldn't load XPCOM How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

and i fix this error updating (gtk library)
update gtk2 to gtk3.Firefox latest versions required gtk3 in centos.
How to install gtk3.

> $ yum install gtk3-devel

After install firefox and it's work fine.Test it work fine.

> $ firefox -V

Comment: Guys,
  Any fix on this...? I getting similar error message.

  My setup is that I have a centos 7 machine with shell-command prompt access
  @waruna k, I tried installing gtk3-devel
  It is 2018, what number shall I update it with like gtk10-devel or something?

     --   [QA_User@QA_Automation_Box ~]$ firefox -V
    XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /opt/firefox/libxul.so:
    libXt.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    Couldn't load XPCOM. --

Any insights will be quite a helpful assistance in this regard ....

Comment: Installed firefox from rpm package manager as " wget http://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/7.7.1908/updates/x86_64/Packages/firefox-68.3.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm"  with necessary dependencies "mozilla-filesystem, redhat-indexhtml, libstartup-notification-1.so.0()(64bit) and libXt.so.6()(64bit)"

Comment: Observations:- 1. Executing firefox command from Terminal client like Mobaxterm opens up a Firefox browser window in native machine -- 2. Executing within  terminal of putty results into error of 'cannot open session' -- 3. In both of the earlier use cases, it starts out without a11y support -- 4. From geckodriver, it executes successfully